# Heat equation fundamental solution

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-differential-equations, physics, heat-equation

The following is from a book of PDEs and I have cannot seem to figure out a particular step in it with regard to the derivation of the fundamental solution of the heat equation. I have highlighted it in red. I would much appreciate if someone could help me out with it or if possible suggest me a text which has a more detailed approach than what I have attached. Thanks!
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
e^{-r}\int^r e^\sigma\,\sigma^{-1/2}\,d\sigma&= e^{-r}\Bigl(e^\sigma\,\sigma^{-1/2}\Bigr|^r+\frac12\int^re^\sigma\,\sigma^{-3/2}\,d\sigma\Bigr)\\
&=r^{-1/2}+\frac{e^{-r}}{2}\int^re^\sigma\,\sigma^{-3/2}\,d\sigma\\
&=r^{-1/2}+O(r^{-3/2}),
\end{align}$$
since
$$
\lim_{r\to\infty}\frac{\int^re^\sigma\,\sigma^{-3/2}\,d\sigma}{r^{-3/2}e^r}=\lim_{r\to\infty}\frac{e^r\,r^{-3/2}}{(-(3/2)r^{-5/2}+r^{-3/2})e^r}=\lim_{r\to\infty}\frac{1}{-(3/2)r^{-1}+1}=1.
$$

Comment: Thanks but how did you directly show that the integral is equal to $O(r^{-3/2})$

Comment: Did you get that by what you showed using the limit?

Comment: The limit computation shows that $$e^{-r}\int^re^\sigma\sigma^{-3/2}\,d\sigma\sim r^{-3/2}.$$

Comment: Thanks. Just another question if you don't mind. Isn't it possible to use the Taylor series to derive the same thing?

Comment: Since $r\to\infty$ I do not see how you would do that, other than doing the change of variable $\sigma=1/s$.

Comment: The change of variable I tried is actually $\sqrt{\sigma}=s/2$

Comment: You will still need that Taylor expansion around $\infty$.

Comment: Anyway the whole point is setting $A=0$ as the integral is not bounded right?

Comment: In your case when r approaches infinity I cannot see how it becomes unbounded though